# Using a project on the WSL2 filesystem with NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, netbeans-12

I'm using [WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10. I'm also using NetBeans 12.1.

How do I open a project that is located on the WSL filesystem with NetBeans? In Windows Explorer the filesystem is [accessible as `\\wsl$`](https://www.howtogeek.com/426749/how-to-access-your-linux-wsl-files-in-windows-10/), but how do I get NetBeans to open that?

Answer (score 5):

As a workaround you could create a shortcut for \wsl$ (on the desktop, e.g.), open the shortcut in the "open project" dialog and navigate from there.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/4133

Answer (score 2):

You can try to mount WSL folder as a network drive.

[image]

For example, I mounted `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu` as `U:\` network drive and have access to my projects folder as `U:\projects`

Projects can now be correctly added to NetBeans and can be worked on.

Comment: the solution is working, but the time for displaying external changes is significantly increased